# Android Studios build preview not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I have started doing a tutorial for building android apps using Android Studios and Kotlin. So I am very new to Android Studios. I just tried to make a new application using a basic activity. The first time, the build didn't succeed so I re-opened the application and after some time, the build succeeded but the preview still didn't load saying the build didn't complete.

At first I thought maybe it just took some time so I waited 30 minutes and it still didnt work.[image]

Some of the code is red so is there something I did wrong while setting it up? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following options one by one.

1. restart android studio
2. clean & rebuild project
3. file -> Invalidate caches and restart

Comment: then I guess some of your libraries in build.gradle is outdated. Can you post it or try to update some of them

Comment: Just updated it and created a new project. It seems to be working. Thank you so much!